# JSON-RPC ou RESTFULL?

Tags: json, web-service, api, rest, restful

Entre desenvolver uma API utilizando JSON-RPC ou REST(RESTFULL), gostaria de saber em quais casos existem vantagens/desvantagens na utilização de um ou de outro.

OBS:
Pode ser por meio de conhecimentos/experiências ou fontes de referência.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Um dos equívocos mais comuns é que qualquer chamada que utilize os verbos de HTTP, como GET, PUT, POST ao invés de usar ligações SOAP para expor um end-point de serviço é chamado de "RESTful". Esta indefinição da linha entre REST e XML-RPC (ou JSON-RPC, etc) tem algumas consequências muito significativas na prática.

Confundindo serviços web POX como "REST", muitas implementações de API web nunca exploram plenamente a arquitetura RESTful.

**REST vs RPC**

REST não é um framework como o WCF, um protocolo como HTTP, um framework como JAX-RS, ou um formato de comunicação como SOAP. REST é uma arquitetura, uma forma estruturada de representar uma solução de software - especificamente, expondo os aspectos de uma solução para um conjunto de clientes-consumidores remotos. O princípio central do REST é que esses aspectos de uma solução podem ser modelados como recursos que o cliente pode consumir ou interagir.

Este pensamento orientado a recursos, e não aos detalhes de implementação de como se dá a comunicação entre cliente e servidor, é o que REST é realmente. Esta é a diferença fundamental que separa APIs RESTful reais da RPC baseados em verbos de HTTP.

**Por que isso é importante?**
A abordagem RESTful nos permite modelar os nossos objetos de domínio como URLs hierárquicas consistentes com mapeamento semântico e previsível (vagamente) para CRUD. Como HTTP vem com códigos de erro padrão, tipos de MIME e, geralmente, faz a maior parte do trabalho pesado, é interessante se beneficiar da não necessidade de manter uma pilha de protocolos desenvolvidos pelo usuário, e que está sujeita a modificação freqüente.

O problema fundamental com RPC é acoplamento. Clientes RPC tornam-se intimamente ligados ao serviço de implementação de várias maneiras e torna-se muito difícil mudar implementação do serviço sem quebrar clientes.

Considere o seguinte exemplo de APIs HTTP que modelam as ordens de um restaurante.

- A API RPC pensa em termos de "verbos", expondo a funcionalidade do restaurante com chamadas de funções que aceitam parâmetros e chama estas funções através do verbo HTTP que parece mais apropriado - um 'GET' para uma consulta, e assim por diante, mas o nome do verbo é puramente incidental e não tem qualquer influência real sobre a funcionalidade real, uma vez que você está chamando uma URL diferente a cada vez. Códigos de retorno são codificados manualmente, e fazem parte do contrato de serviço.
- A API REST, por sua vez, modelam as várias entidades do domínio do problema como recursos, e usa os verbos de HTTP para representar operações contra estes recursos - POST para criar, PUT para atualizar, e GET para ler, recuperar. Cada um desses verbos, invocados na mesma URL (recurso), fornecem uma funcionalidade diferente. Códigos de retorno HTTP comuns são usados ​​para transmitir o status das solicitações.

**Exemplos:**

*Adicionar um pedido:*

- **RPC**:  `http://MyRestaurant:8080/Orders/PlaceOrder (POST: <Order OrderNumber="asdf"><Appetizer><Appetizer><Entree>Tacos</Entree><! --Rest of the order--></Order>)`
- **REST**: `http://MyRestaurant:8080/Orders/Order?OrderNumber=asdf (POST:
  <Order><Appetizer><Appetizer><Entree>Tacos</Entree><! --Rest of the
  order--></Order>)`

*Recuperando um pedido:*

- **RPC**:  `http://MyRestaurant:8080/Orders/GetOrder?OrderNumber=asdf (GET)`
- **REST**: `http://MyRestaurant:8080/Orders/Order?OrderNumber=asdf (GET)`

*Atualizando um pedido:*

- **RPC**:  `http://MyRestaurant:8080/Orders/UpdateOrder (PUT: <Order OrderNumber="asdf"><Appetizer><Appetizer><Entree>Pineapple
  Tacos</Entree><! --Rest of the order--></Order>)`
- **REST**: `http://MyRestaurant:8080/Orders/Order?OrderNumber=asdf (PUT: <Order><Appetizer><Appetizer><Entree>Pineapple Tacos</Entree><!
  --Rest of the order--></Order>)`

Referências:

- [REST vs RPC - What is RESTful](https://sites.google.com/site/wagingguerillasoftware/rest-series/what-is-restful-rest-vs-rpc)
- [Stackoverflow: REST vs JSON-RPC](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15116562/747802)